# MySQL selecting rows when a linked field matches

Tags: mysql, select, field

Im trying to build a query where i get all the variants where the content matches the search.
For example, based on the table below i want to get all variants that contains the content = "red"

```
 -------------------------------------------
| ID | Product | Variant | Option | Content |
 -------------------------------------------
|  1 | Shirt   | 1       | size   | S       |   
|  2 | Shirt   | 1       | color  | red     |
|  3 | Shirt   | 2       | size   | M       |   
|  4 | Shirt   | 2       | color  | red     |
|  5 | Shirt   | 3       | size   | L       |   
|  6 | Shirt   | 3       | color  | red     |
|  7 | Shirt   | 4       | size   | M       |
|  8 | Shirt   | 4       | color  | blue    |
 -------------------------------------------
```

I would like the results to be something like:

```
 -------------------------------------------
| ID | Product | Variant | Option | Content |
 -------------------------------------------
|  1 | Shirt   | 1       | size   | S       |   
|  2 | Shirt   | 1       | color  | red     |
|  3 | Shirt   | 2       | size   | M       |   
|  4 | Shirt   | 2       | color  | red     |
|  5 | Shirt   | 3       | size   | L       |   
|  6 | Shirt   | 3       | color  | red     |
 -------------------------------------------
```

And the result when the content = M, would be something like this

```
 -------------------------------------------
| ID | Product | Variant | Option | Content |
 -------------------------------------------
|  3 | Shirt   | 2       | size   | M       |   
|  4 | Shirt   | 2       | color  | red     |
|  7 | Shirt   | 4       | size   | M       |
|  8 | Shirt   | 4       | color  | blue    |
 -------------------------------------------
```

I hope this makes sense. 
Thanks!

I made a fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63e64e/2

Comment: great questions come with sqlfiddle.com +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join

```
SELECT v1.*
FROM variant AS v1
JOIN variant AS v2 ON v1.variant = v2.variant
WHERE v2.content = 'red'
```

This is functionaly equivalent to Tin Tran's query, but doesn't require writing a subquery, so it's a little simpler. You'd need to check the `EXPLAIN` output to ensure that they're processed the same.

Comment: Thank you, worked like charm, i i could be able to build a second filter here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be3bbe/6  using the following query SELECT v1.*
FROM variant AS v1
JOIN variant AS v2 ON v1.variant = v2.variant WHERE v2.content = 'S'
JOIN variant AS v3 ON v1.variant = v3.variant WHERE v3.content = 'winter'

Comment: All the `JOIN` clauses come first, then a single `WHERE` clause with `AND` between the conditions.

Comment: you're probably wanting to do `SELECT v1.* FROM variant AS v1 JOIN variant AS v2 ON v1.variant = v2.variant WHERE v2.content = 'S' OR v2.content = 'winter'`

Comment: Actually that 'OR' tag doesnt work it bring everyting... i posted the worng version of the query, this one is the correct that is working: SELECT v1.* FROM variant AS v1 JOIN variant AS v2 ON v1.variant = v2.variant AND v2.content = 'S' JOIN variant AS v3 ON v1.variant = v3.variant AND v3.content = 'winter'

Comment: @Rafanake In general, conditions on a single table should be in the `WHERE` clause, and the `ON` clause should only be used for conditions relating the tables being joined. The exception to this is outer joins, where you put conditions on the child table in the `ON` clause as well. However, putting the extra conditions in `ON` works equivalently.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.id,v.product,v.variant,v.option,v.content
FROM variant v
INNER JOIN (SELECT variant FROM variant WHERE content = 'red')v2
ON v.variant = v2.variant
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

just change `'red'` to `'M'` if you want to get your other result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63e64e/7

I noticed in your sqlfiddle it has a variant of M and Yellow that will show up in the result if you set the 'red' string to 'M'

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM variant
WHERE
variant.variant 
IN
(
  SELECT variant.variant 
  FROM variant 
  WHERE variant.content = 'red'
)
```

This should be relatively easy to understand. You have an inner query that first does a search for every variant with the option available. Then you have the outer query that searches for all values of all variants that were returned from the variant search. A more elegant way to write this could be something like,

```
SELECT *
FROM variant
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT variant2.variant 
  FROM variant variant2 
  WHERE variant2.content = 'red'
) variant2
ON variant.variant = variant2.variant
```

In this example, you would have to name at least one of the returned tables to differentiate them both. This is because you are calling two instances of the same table.

```
SELECT *
FROM variant
JOIN variant AS variant2 ON variant.variant = variant2.variant
WHERE variant2.content = 'red'
```

Here's another example that outputs the same result. The difference with this one is you are running it in a single query.

A good source to learn about joins from can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

One of my favorite diagrams on joins can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg It's missing a few tricks, but it does give a good basic idea of what you can do with joins.

Comment: Thank you, ill check those links!

Comment: MySQL is notoriously bad at optimizing `WHERE col IN (SELECT ...)` queries, so try to avoid them.